# Show cdir values

Tags: gdb

When I tried to see what are the directories gdb try to search for source files, I used `show directories`, it output a variable:

```
(gdb) show directories
Source directories searched: $cdir:$cwd
```

But how can I show value of the two variables: `cdir` and `cwd`? Tried `show` or `p` didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how can I show value of the two variables: `cdir` and `cwd`

The `$cdir` [stands for](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) compilation directory (if one is recorded) and is specific to the current source file.

The command `info source` should show you info for current source file, including the compilation directory:

```
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcb8) at t.c:3
3         return 0;
(gdb) info source
Current source file is t.c
Compilation directory is /tmp     <<<=== this is $cdir
Located in /tmp/t.c
Contains 4 lines.
Source language is c.
Producer is GNU C11 7.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

The `$cwd` stands for current working directory, which you can examine with the `pwd` command:

```
(gdb) pwd
Working directory /tmp.
```